# Remove WP Core canonical for category pagination

Tags: categories, permalinks, pagination, noindex, rel-canonical

It seems that WP is adding a canonical to the root of my pagination, and no indexing all other pages on Category pages.

For example, /locations/residential/?_page=2 is no-index, and gives /locations/residential/ as canonical.

I have tried this to attempt to remove this for these Category pages, but Screaming Frog still says the pagination is no-index and rel=canonical to the root page.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical','custom_disable_redirect_canonical' ); 
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ){
    if ( is_category() ) $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Any idea what I amdoing wrong?

Comment: WordPress doesn’t set pagination pages to noindex. Are you using an SEO plugin? Also, why does your pagination parameter have an underscore? Have you tried to implement your own pagination?

Comment: I am using Yoast. I think the issue is appearing as i used a plugin to replace the grid on Category pages, and this is the pagination style it uses.

I can set this to use my default theme pagination which is /page/2 which does indeed fix the issue.

However, other areas of the site work correctly and still have pagination in the format/?_page=2

Comment: Perhaps another question. If I set the category pages to use the default /page/2/ format, is there a rewrite rule I can use to change the other pagination to match.

So I would need a rewrite rule to change /?_page=2 to /page/2/  to make the other areas of the site match